# How to Zoom when mouse hover over image?

Tags: angular

When i hover my mouse on the image,it should zoom just like facebook and flipkart.!

i have tried with the ngx-image-zoom.but i have only one image which is comming from api and want to integrate with zoom in feature in the api.

```
.html file

-->
<ngx-image-zoom
    [thumbImage]=myThumbnail
    [fullImage]=myFullresImage
></ngx-image-zoom>
```

```
.ts file 
-->
  myThumbnail = "https://wittlock.github.io/ngx-image-zoom/assets/thumb.jpg";
  myFullresImage = "https://wittlock.github.io/ngx-image-zoom/assets/fullres.jpg";
```

npm install ngx-image-zoom --save
flipkart and amazon type zoom in in these angular.!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: yes lucifer, i have only 1 image source.

Comment: how to integrate it with the mouse hover.?

Comment: capture mouse hover event, zoom image

Comment: can you eloborate..?

Comment: Read manual: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-zoom, set zoom mode `hover`

Comment: but i have only 1 image ,can it be done..?

Comment: You can test it in 10-20 seconds in any online sandbox

Comment: you can use css to get that effect. check this: https://w3bits.com/css-image-hover-zoom/

Comment: i want to zoom in these sense flipkart and amazon ,when we look image of any product can zoom and watch it at any dimension.!

Answer (score 0):

To implement image zoom feature like Flipkart and Amazon in Angular, you can try npm package [ng-img-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-magnifier).

```
<ng-img-magnifier [thumbImage]='img' [fullImage]='img2'
    [top]='top' [right]='right'
    [lensWidth]='lensewidth' [lensHeight]='lensheight'
    [resultWidth]='resultWidth' [resultHeight]='resultheight'
    [imgWidth]='imgWidth' [imgHeight]='imgheight'>
</ng-img-magnifier>
```

This package provide full customization and support.

I hope this will resolve your issue.